# Add value to column based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dateframe as shown below

| ID | value | country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | DE |
| 21 | 10 | IND |

I want to add +4 to the 'value' column when country = DE such that the dataframe becomes

| ID | value | country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 24 | DE |
| 21 | 10 | IND |

I tried the following code but Its not working and I am getting an error

```
def add_buffer(df):
    if df.country == 'DE':
        df.value = df.value+4
    else:
        df.value = df.value
    return df
```

```
df1 = add_buffer(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.loc` to update `value` only where `country` is equal to DE

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': {0: 1, 1: 21}, 'value': {0: 20, 1: 10}, 'country': {0: 'DE', 1: 'IND'}})
df.loc[df['country'].eq('DE'),'value']+=4

print(df)
```

Output

```
   ID  value country
0   1     24      DE
1  21     10     IND
```